# How do I fix the display of the Total bill variable?

Tags: c++, project

So here is what the output is:

```
           Roller Coaster City Amusement Park

        Enter number of Children Tickets or -1 to stop...10
        Enter number of Adult Tickets......11


           Roller Coaster City Amusement Park
                 -------------------------

               Tickets      Price      Total
     Children    10         10.00     100.00
     Adults      11         25.00     275.00

                 21
   Security Fee                        15.00

     Total Bill                       410.00

          Cash Received........
```

The total bill is supposed to output 390.00.

Here's my C++ code:

```
 // Author:         Bart Allen
// Source file:     amuseOne.cpp
/*
Description:     A program designed to output the number of tickets being purchased 
                for the entry into the amusement park
*/  
// IDE used:    Visual Studio 2015 

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

//the constants of the function 
const double CHILDPRICE = 12.00;
const double CHILDDISC = 10.00;
const double ADULTPRICE = 25.00;
const double Secfee = 15.00;


int main ()
{

    //appropiate variable declarations
    double childTotalDisc;
    int childTix;
    int adultTix;
    double childTotal;
    double adultTotal;
    double totalBill;
    double payment;
    double change;
    int totalTickets;
    int confirmNUM = 100;
    //Outputs the title of the amusement park
    cout << "\n           Roller Coaster City Amusement Park" << endl << endl;

    cout << "\tEnter number of Children Tickets or -1 to stop...";
    cin >> childTix;
    while (childTix != -1)
    {
        cout << "\tEnter number of Adult Tickets......";
        cin >> adultTix;



        //Calculations are placed here 
        //childTotalDisc = childTix * CHILDDISC;
        childTotal = childTix * CHILDPRICE;
        adultTotal = adultTix * ADULTPRICE;
        totalBill = childTotal + adultTotal;
        totalTickets = childTix + adultTix;


        //Sets the decimal place to only display two decimal places 
        cout.setf(ios::fixed);
        cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
        cout.precision(2);
        //Outputs the number of tickets being purchased, along with the calculated totals 
        cout << "\n\n           Roller Coaster City Amusement Park";
        cout << "\n                 -------------------------";
        cout << "\n\n               Tickets      Price      Total\n";
        if (childTix >= 8)
        {
            childTotal = CHILDDISC * childTix;
            cout << "     Children   " << setw(3) << childTix
                                       << setw(14) << CHILDDISC
                                       << setw(11) << childTotal;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "     Children   " << setw(3) << childTix
                                       << setw(14) << CHILDPRICE
                                       << setw(11) << childTotal;
        }


        cout << "\n     Adults   " << setw(5) << adultTix
                                   << setw(14) << ADULTPRICE
                                   << setw(11) << adultTotal;
        cout << "\n\n            " << setw(7) << totalTickets;

        if ((totalTickets >= 20) || (childTix >= 14))
        {
            cout << "\n   Security Fee  " << setw(27) << Secfee;
            cout << "\n\n     Total Bill  " << setw(27) << totalBill + Secfee;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "\n\n     Total Bill  " << setw(27) << totalBill;
        }

        //asks for the users input of amount of money being submitted to cover the final cost 
        cout << "\n\n\t  Cash Received........";
        cin >> payment;
        do
        {
            cout << "\tCash must be >= Total Bill ";

            cout << "\n\n\t  Cash Received........";
            cin >> payment;
        } while (payment < totalBill);
        change = payment - totalBill;
        cout << "\n     Change     " << setw(28.5) << change << endl;
        cout << "     Confirmation number =  " << confirmNUM++ << endl;

        cout << "\n    Enter number of Children Tickets or -1 to stop...";
        cin >> childTix;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Literally that is my only issue with this program, luckily no errors have occurred and this is for my project! Any suggestions would help!

Comment: My suggestion would be to watch the local values with a debugger.

Comment: Nothing is displaying could it be that the if statement isn't as efficient??

Comment: You have missed this `if (childTix >= 8)` check where you calculate `childTotal`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already done the `totalBill` calculation using `childTotal`, calculated from `CHILDPRICE`, and later you change `childTotal` to be calculated from `CHILDDISC`, and forget to update `totalBill` accordingly.

Therefore, I suggest, that you do the `childTix >=8` check, where you calculate everything else and leave the rest of the code to just display things and not do any more calculations.

Replace:

```
childTotal = childTix * CHILDPRICE;
adultTotal = adultTix * ADULTPRICE;
totalBill = childTotal + adultTotal;
totalTickets = childTix + adultTix;
```

with:

```
if (childTix >= 8)
{
 childTotal = childTix * CHILDDISC;
}
else
{
 childTotal = childTix * CHILDPRICE;
}
adultTotal = adultTix * ADULTPRICE;
totalBill = childTotal + adultTotal;
totalTickets = childTix + adultTix;
```

And remove `childTotal = CHILDDISC * childTix;` from where the display logic is.

**Edit:**

You are just displaying `totalBill + Secfee` not actually adding `Secfee` to `totalBill`.

So replace:

```
if ((totalTickets >= 20) || (childTix >= 14))
{
    cout << "\n   Security Fee  " << setw(27) << Secfee;
    cout << "\n\n     Total Bill  " << setw(27) << totalBill + Secfee;
}
else
{
    cout << "\n\n     Total Bill  " << setw(27) << totalBill;
}
```

with:

```
if ((totalTickets >= 20) || (childTix >= 14))
{
    cout << "\n   Security Fee  " << setw(27) << Secfee;
    totalBill += Secfee;
    cout << "\n\n     Total Bill  " << setw(27) << totalBill;
}
else
{
    cout << "\n\n     Total Bill  " << setw(27) << totalBill;
}
```

Also, you should use `while` instead of `do while` here, otherwise it would reask for input even if right input was given, because `do while` is meant to run at least once.

So replace:

```
cout << "\n\n\t  Cash Received........";
cin >> payment;
do
{
    cout << "\tCash must be >= Total Bill ";

    cout << "\n\n\t  Cash Received........";
    cin >> payment;
} while (payment < totalBill);
```

with:

```
cout << "\n\n\t  Cash Received........";
cin >> payment;
while (payment < totalBill)
{
    cout << "\tCash must be >= Total Bill ";

    cout << "\n\n\t  Cash Received........";
    cin >> payment;
}
```

**Edit2:**

If you still wish to use `do while` then do the following:

```
//cout << "\n\n\t  Cash Received........"; remove this line
//cin >> payment; remove this line
do
{
    cout << "\n\n\t  Cash Received........";
    cin >> payment;
    if(payment < totalBill)
    {
     cout << "\tCash must be >= Total Bill ";
    }
}
while (payment < totalBill);
```

Comment: I did that, thank you that definitely helped with the display but the calculations are all off now

Comment: What happened to the calculations? Where exactly did you add those lines? Because it is working fine at my end.

Comment: Total Bill                       390.00

          Cash Received........300
        Cash must be >= Total Bill

          Cash Received........400

     Change                            25.00

Comment: the cash received for this should be 10 dollars but instead it says 25 dollars

Comment: Ahh.. for that. See the edit I am making to the post.

Comment: Okay I see the edit and Thank you so much! It works! now I see why, and trust me I wish I could get rid of the do while loop but my professor wanted us to incorporate it within our code at that specific spot!

Comment: Then see an edit again of how you could use `do while` here.

Comment: Do you think you can explain why I should code it that way?? trust me I am asking so I can understand :)

Comment: Try the code first to see that it works. Basically, what is happening is, that we are using the guarantee provided by `do while` that it will run at least once, to take the first input. And then we know that the loop would re-iterate if `payment < totalBill` so we add another `if(payment < totalBill)` to display the error beforehand, for the next iteration of input to proceed. This way if the input is correct in the first iteration no error is displayed and the loop exits. Is it clear now?

Comment: Glad to help! Welcome to SO. If this, or any other answer solved your problem, then you should [upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow) and/or [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it, so that later viewers may track down the solution.

Comment: Yes that makes perfect sense but actually when I tested the code it creates a blank spot and then asks the user for Cash Received

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104362/discussion-between-ahmed-akhtar-and-bartholomew-allen).